# Julia - Plotting files in directory

Tags: plot, julia, data-processing

I'm new to Julia, and I'm trying to generate plots from data files in a directory.  Each file is a separate plot.  I have the following code to generate an array, `allfiles', of all the txt files in the directory.

```
for filename in readdir(pwd())
    if endswith(filename, ".txt")
       push!(allfiles,filename)
    end
end
```

I also have a function `myFunction` to process the data in the file.  This function expects the filename.  How do I apply `myFunction` to each filename in `allfiles`?  I've tried the dot syntax, and it returns the following error.

`MethodError: no method matching myFunction(::Array{String,1})`

I've also tried `map`, `mapslices`, `broadcast`, and putting `myFunction` into a loop iterating over the length of `allfiles` (though maybe not correctly).

EDIT, `mFunction` code added.  It's a mess and doesn't work as is.  The idea is I have CSV data files with formatting information in the lines between the data sets.  Line 3 of the data file has the number of data sets in each file, `nsets`, and line 4 has the number of data points, `npts` in set 1.  I'd like to set up the function to read the number of data sets, then read and plot each data set.

```
function myFileFunction(file::String)
  for i=1:length(allfiles)

    m=readdlm(allfiles[i],',' )
    m2=readdlm(allfiles[i], ',', skipstart=4)
    nsets = m[3,1]
    for j=1:nsets
    npts[j] = m[4,1]
    npts2[j] = m[4+npts1+3,1];
    npts3[j] = m[4+npts1+npts2+3+3,1];
    start1 = 1;
    end1 = (start1+npts1-1);
    start2 = (end1+4);
    end2 = (start2+npts2-1);
    start3 = (end2+4);
    end3 = (start3+npts3-1);

    x1 = Float64.(m2[start1:end1,1]);
    y1 = Float64.(m2[start1:end1,2]);
    x2 = Float64.(m2[start2:end2,1]);
    y2 = Float64.(m2[start2:end2,2]);
    x3 = Float64.(m2[start3:end3,1]);
    y3 = Float64.(m2[start3:end3,2]);

    plot(x1,y1)
    plot!(x2,y2)
    plot!(x3,y3)

return "Done"

end
end
```

Comment: try `map(myFunction, filename for filename in readdir() if endswith(filename, ".txt"))` if your function returns something meaningful or `foreach(myFunction, filename for filename in readdir() if endswith(filename, ".txt"))` if you do not want to collect its return value.

Comment: Thanks, but that returns a similar error.  I think the issue is with `myFunction`, and I'll have to work on that some more.

Comment: if you post a code of `myFunction` I can have a look at it. I tested my code with simple `myFunction` implementations.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a mess, so I appreciate your help.

Comment: The start of the function should be: `function myFunction(filename::AbstractString)
    m=readdlm(filename,',' )
    m2=readdlm(filename, ',', skipstart=4)
`. And I guess `return "Done"` is not needed.

Comment: I appreciate it, thanks.